# SSRS drilldown in text box tag cloud

Tags: reporting-services, lookup, drillthrough

I have made a tag cloud using custom code from [SQL Jason](http://www.sqljason.com/2012/03/making-tag-cloud-with-ssrs-rich-text.html) which displays the words using custom code`Public Function BuildHtmlTag(ByVal Keywrd as String, ByVal Num as Integer, ByVal FColor as String) AS String
HtmlTag = HtmlTag & "" & Keywrd & " "

End Function`
This works fine but I would like to drill through to another report on the words. I have tried drill through expression in the textbox using Lookup, MultiLookUp and LookupSet functions but can only succeed in getting the first value returned. Does anyone know how to either return multiple values to a text box that I could use for the drillthrough action, or how to adjust the custom code to allow drillthrough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust the code to have links to other reports by using the `<a>` tag in the HTML. You'll have to build a url to the report that you want to link to & use parameters.

For example:

```
Public Function BuildHtmlTag(ByVal Keywrd as String, ByVal Num as Integer) AS String

    HtmlTag = HtmlTag & "<a href=""http://foo/reports/reportb?a=" & Keywrd & """><font size=""" & FontSize & """>" & Keywrd & " (" &  Num & ") </font></a>"

    Return Keywrd

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response which is correct! I amended the public function code to include ByVal WordID as integer and to build the WordID into the html string. I also needed to change the report action to Go to URL (not Go to Report) as I had previously.

Comment: @jt000 How can I build a URL for my report? all I see is a Report path from the report properties.

Comment: @KimJaca - The url for a report is defined by the folder the report is saved in. You can find the URL of your report by opening it in the browser & copying it out of the address bar.

Comment: @jt000 ah so you were talking about the report URL when the report is already deployed in the report server? I see, thank you :) Hmm. how about, how can I pass the parameters?

Comment: @KimJaca - Via URL Access you can pass them to the report using the query string. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155391.aspx for details (and some other things you can do w/ url access)